# ASP .net - debugging javascript (quick breakpoints issue)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, debugging, breakpoints

Sometimes I can set breakpoints in my javascript, sometimes I can't - why is this? I can't seem to find whatever it is that would determine whether I can debug it or not. I know I can debug the dynamic page, but occasionally I'll be able to set breakpoints in my original code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use following to debug javaScript

- Put `breakpoint` inside javascript. Using VS2010 you can debug the javascript. You will need to enable javascript debugging in IE by unchecking both of the `Disable script debugging` from IE => Options => Advanced.
- Use `console.log` to log the messages from javaScript

Hope this info helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Amar. My question is more specific to visual studio though I feel - I simply cannot set a breakpoint anywhere in the javascript (clicking does nothing) on occasions, and then at other times I can set breakpoints without a problem!? Thanks.

Comment: Not sure about this but, in such cases try putting `breakpoint` keyword in the javascript. I have never faced such issue so far (lucky me).

Comment: I've had a quick look around and using the debugger keyword will do me for now. Thanks Amar.

Comment: Great some break through finally.

Comment: what about while using Safari and Firefox and Chrome?

Comment: You can use developer tools provided by the webkit browser (chrome and safari). For firefox, firebug is great tool.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

--javascript code......

debugger; // stops execution and can start debugging

--javascript code......